# Useful way to convert string to dictionary using python

Tags: json, python-3.x, string, dictionary, converters

I have the below `string` as input:

```
'name SP2, status Online, size 4764771 MB, free 2576353 MB, path /dev/sde, log 210 MB, port 5660, guid 7478a0141b7b9b0d005b30b0e60f3c4d, clusterUuid -8650609094877646407--116798096584060989, disks /dev/sde /dev/sdf /dev/sdg, dare 0'
```

I wrote function which convert it to `dictionary` using `python`:

```
def str_2_json(string):
    str_arr = string.split(',')
    #str_arr{0} = name SP2
    #str_arr{1} = status Online
    json_data = {}
    for i in str_arr:
        #remove whitespaces
        stripped_str = " ".join(i.split())  # i.strip()
        subarray = stripped_str.split(' ')
        #subarray{0}=name
        #subarray{1}=SP2
        key = subarray[0] #key: 'name'
        value = subarray[1] #value: 'SP2'
        json_data[key] = value
        #{dict 0}='name': SP2'
        #{dict 1}='status': online'
    return json_data
```

The `return` turns the `dictionary` into `json` (it has `jsonfiy`).

Is there a simple/elegant way to do it better?

Comment: Can any of these values have an embedded comma and if so, is it escaped in some way? What are the rules followed to encode the string in the first place?

Comment: This in the input I get and I can't change it, so I have to work only with that

Comment: But the question is about the rules for creating the data. There are a lot of questions like whether a field can have an embedded comma, single valued things like `name` to be in a list, should `disks` always be in a list, etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is good, except for a couple weird things:

- You aren't creating a *JSON* anything, so to avoid any confusion I suggest you don't name your returned dictionary `json_data` or your function `str_2_json`. JSON, or **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation is just that -- a standard of denoting an object as text. The objects themselves have nothing to do with JSON.
- You can use `i.strip()` instead of joining the splitted string (not sure why you did it this way, since you commented out `i.strip()`)
- Some of your values contain multiple spaces (e.g. `"size 4764771 MB"` or `"disks /dev/sde /dev/sdf /dev/sdg"`).  By your code, you end up everything after the second space in such strings. To avoid this, do `stripped_str.split(' ', 1)` which limits how many times you want to split the string.

Other than that, you could create a dictionary in one line using the `dict()` constructor and a generator expression:

```
def str_2_dict(string):
    data = dict(item.strip().split(' ', 1) for item in string.split(','))
    return data

print(str_2_dict('name SP2, status Online, size 4764771 MB, free 2576353 MB, path /dev/sde, log 210 MB, port 5660, guid 7478a0141b7b9b0d005b30b0e60f3c4d, clusterUuid -8650609094877646407--116798096584060989, disks /dev/sde /dev/sdf /dev/sdg, dare 0'))
```

Outputs:

```
{
 'name': 'SP2',
 'status': 'Online',
 'size': '4764771 MB',
 'free': '2576353 MB',
 'path': '/dev/sde',
 'log': '210 MB',
 'port': '5660',
 'guid': '7478a0141b7b9b0d005b30b0e60f3c4d',
 'clusterUuid': '-8650609094877646407--116798096584060989',
 'disks': '/dev/sde /dev/sdf /dev/sdg',
 'dare': '0'
}
```

This is probably the same (practically, in terms of efficiency / time) as writing out the full loop:

```
def str_2_dict(string):
    data = dict()
    for item in string.split(','):
        key, value = item.strip().split(' ', 1) 
        data[key] = value
    return data
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with regex

```
import re

def parseString(s):
    dict(re.findall('(?:(\S+) ([^,]+)(?:, )?)', s))

sample = "name SP1, status Offline, size 4764771 MB, free 2406182 MB, path /dev/sdb, log 230 MB, port 5660, guid a48134c00cda2c37005b30b0e40e3ed6, clusterUuid -8650609094877646407--116798096584060989, disks /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd, dare 0"

parseString(sample)
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'SP1',
 'status': 'Offline',
 'size': '4764771 MB',
 'free': '2406182 MB',
 'path': '/dev/sdb',
 'log': '230 MB',
 'port': '5660',
 'guid': 'a48134c00cda2c37005b30b0e40e3ed6',
 'clusterUuid': '-8650609094877646407--116798096584060989',
 'disks': '/dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd',
 'dare': '0'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these fields cannot contain internal commas, you can use `re.split` to both split and remove surrounding whitespace. It looks like you have different types of fields that should be handled differently. I've added a guess at a schema handler based on field names that can serve as a template for converting the various fields as needed.

And as noted elsewhere, there is no json so don't use that name.

```
import re

test = 'name SP2, status Online, size 4764771 MB, free 2576353 MB, path /dev/sde, log 210 MB, port 5660, guid 7478a0141b7b9b0d005b30b0e60f3c4d, clusterUuid -8650609094877646407--116798096584060989, disks /dev/sde /dev/sdf /dev/sdg, dare 0'

def decode_data(string):
    str_arr = re.split(r"\s*,\s*", string)
    data = {}
    for entry in str_arr:
        values = re.split(r"\s+", entry)
        key = values.pop(0)
        # schema processing
        if key in ("disks"): # multivalue keys
            data[key] = values
        elif key in ("size", "free"): # convert to int bytes on 2nd value
            multiplier = {"MB":10**6, "MiB":2**20} # todo: expand as needed
            data[key] = int(values[0]) * multiplier[values[1]]
        else:
            data[key] = " ".join(values)
    return data

decoded = decode_data(test)
for kv in sorted(decoded.items()):
    print(kv)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

json_data = json.loads(string)
```

Comment: I clarified the question. My input is not `json string` but just a `string`